# How to prevent Tkinter and Pyserial from blocking entire program execution

Tags: python, tkinter, tweepy

I am currently writing a program that involves the usage of Tkinter (for GUI), Pyserial (serial communication with a device), and Tweepy.  The current flow of execution is as follow:

1. GUI class is instantiated (based on Tkinter).  This set of code uses Tkinter's standard key binding functions as well.
2. GUI class creates a non-blocking Serial connection internally.  This is only used for writing, not reading.
3. Program then proceeds to create a Tweepy Stream instance, and listens for Tweets.

The GUI, and Tweepy instances work fine separately.  However, when called sequentially, the stops at (2).  Tweepy is only initialized after the Tkinter window is closed.

Is there a way to make both Tweepy and the GUI work concurrently (similar to multithreading, except that the objects should have references to each other?)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.  I used the threading class.

Apparently, I just had to call the GUI initializer method using `thread_1 = threading.Thread()` and `thread_1.start()`.  The other functions did not have to be run as threads.

These might prove helpful for anyone who has encountered the same problem: http://softwareramblings.com/2008/06/running-functions-as-threads-in-python.html